# PDF parsing lib for Android which can be used to extract embedded digital certificate from a pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am trying to extract an embedded certificate (acrobatsecuritysettings) from a PDF file. This is for an Android App. Does anyone know about any java library specific to Android which can be used to read the attached certificate content of a PDF file? Appreciate your help much. Thanks.